# Websites for creating tournaments with different starting positions

Tags: tournament, online, websites

I'd like to create tournament for my students where I specify the starting positions.

Which websites allows users to create tournaments with different starting positions?

Comment: At chess.com this can be surely done, but with a payment account.

Comment: I'm still figuring out why it keeps saying that I need to have the 10% win ratio. I took a premium trial membership.

Comment: In club tournament custom starting position is not possible.

Comment: see answer above. french wondeful lichess team allows it i guess, but they do what they can, and probably if economy is not a trouble, chess.com is more accurated for any ECO FIDE oficial starting positions (well they migth change a bit what FIDE says but this is a free world)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

**For free**

at https://lichess.org. Go to the "Play" tab, and select "Tournaments." Assuming that you have a lichess account, (*all they need for that is your e-mail, and they do not spam it*) you will see an option to create a tournament. Once you select that option, you will be able to specify the start position in the tournament (this position must be an opening with an ECO code).

If you wish to have *only your students* playing in the tournament, you can make the tournament private (password required to enter) and send the password to your students.

You can also play a game (not tournament) from *any legal position* (opening, endgame, middlegame, whatever) via the board editor, which is under the "tools" tab

Comment: Lichess' selection of starting positions is very small and often not sufficient, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think it's that small. I'm pretty sure it has every named opening (name widely accepted). Also, you can create separate games in any legal position; this could be feasible, especially if he has a small group of students.

Comment: Problem with lichess is the ECO is not deep enough. I tried to create a Berlin tournament and it started with the knight on f6 instead of the Ne4 variation. Kids can easily change to a different line from there. Also lichess does not allow FEN starting positions. But Lichess is the only solution I have now. Chess.com keeps says that it needs 10% win ratio. I couldn't organizers on chess.com so far inspite of getting the premium trial.

Comment: OK. You could also create a study from any position, and have your students challenge each other to a game from there. @ArunJ

Comment: @fuxia Agreed.  The selection of ECOs is horrifically small.  Only one ECO code for the Najdorf, B90.  B94, B96, B97, B98, etc all missing.